# UICollectionView - Cells shouldn't scroll outside the view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

**Situation:**

I use  the `UITableViewController` with static table cells designed in Storyboard. In my first `UITableViewCell` I implemented a nice `UICollectionView`.

However there is one problem: The `UICollectionViewCell` moves out of the frame when I scroll through them. They should stop only in the right positions.[image]

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var topSliderCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var topSliderElement = [TopSliderElement]()    

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return topSliderElement.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "slider cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeSliderCollectionViewCell   
        let slider = topSliderElement[indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLbl.text = slider.tile
        cell.descriptionLBL.text = slider.description

        return cell
    }   
}
```

I tried this:
[image]
This is a possible solution, but it's not working because I don't use a normal `UIViewController`.

**Question: How can I control the cells so that they stop at the right position in the view?**

Comment: Did you try collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that. Is your frame smaller than the full width of the screen and the collectionview don't respect the frame's limits? If so, try enabling "clip to bounds" option of the view

Comment: Clarification: The size of the cards is perfect. I just want them to bounce back to the right position when scrolling so they won’t stop when they are only partly visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set your cells width to be the same with as your `view.frame.width` for this to work properly. If you have any spacing on the sides of your cell (which you do), you'll have to add those together and then minus that from the width. I.e, `view.frame.width - 16`. Once you've done this, you'll have to set `isPagingEnabled` to true in your `UICollecitonView` - this will lock the cell to the centre of the screen when you stop scrolling.